# Removing Excel Table Object Header by VBA

Tags: excel, odbc, vba

I am now working on some VBA code and keep stuck in it.
I am truly appreciated if someone here may help.

Indeed, I am now applying SQL query through Excel ODBC for extracting data from AS400 .
However, I would like to extract the data only without the header.

Therefore, I am applying the following VBA code to remove the table header

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CURRENT_ACCOUNT_QUERY_0001").ShowHeaders = False
```

However, this is not working well as the table header value still remained and the extracted value is shifted down 1 row.

Does any one may suggest the way to remove the table header by VBA code
or Exclude the header row during data extraction.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The `HeaderRowRange` is an integral part of the `ListObject` as such it cannot be deleted. Therefore, if you need to delete the header data then you have to first convert the `ListObject` to a standard excel range using the `Unlist` method of the ListObject.  Add this code into your procedure:

The code is actually deleting the entire header row... *(select the option you need)*

```
Dim rHdr As Range

    Set rHdr = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("CURRENT_ACCOUNT_QUERY_0001").HeaderRowRange
    Lob.Unlist
    'Selec the option required
    rHdr.EntireRow.Delete      'Use this line if you want to delete the entire row
    'rHdr.Delete Shift:=xlUp    'Use this line if you want to delete only the header cells
```

Comment: When creating a table with VBA, I've noticed Excel generating headers by itself (column1, column2 and so forth). Can that behavior be disabled by any chance?